# What does "rows affected" mean in the context of sp_helptext?

Tags: sql, sybase

I just ran an sp_helptext query in Sybase, and in addition to return the text of the stored proc, it also said "1 row affected" - what does this mean? Did it actually do something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly likely this is just a `select` statement.

Try running in Server Management Studio:

```
select * from SomeTableThatYouHave
```

You will have 2 tabs: Results and Messages.

Results will have your grid of data, but Messages will say `(x rows(s) affected)`.

The command you ran was just a read-only `select` statement, so this message does not necessarily mean that anything was modified. It just says how many rows were "used" by the command.

Also, from what is on [the documentation for sp_helptext](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx), it is a read-only operation.